# How to add a third-party jar into android source code

Tags: android

Hi，I am doing some study on Android 6.0 source code and get some trouble.

I want to modify the code of the `PacakageManagerService.java`, which located at the framework layer of Android, and I want to use some tools provided by a third-party jar(such as json-lib.jar).

My question is how to compile this jar into the Android System, so that I can import the `JSONObject` in `PacakageManagerService.java`?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + s > Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project folder -> Open Module Settings -> (Under Module section) select **app** -> Dependencies -> (On Top right corner) Select '**+**' plus icon -> File Dependency -> Select .jar file -> OK. That's it.